# Spinner + Cursor issues

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I honestly have no idea what the deal is with this one.  It should be simple enough, but, for some reason, my spinner is not populating with any data.

```
    final String fields[] = { "siteName","_id" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor ftpCursor = database.query("ftptable", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(ftpCursor);

    Log.i("tag", "getcount result:"+ftpCursor.getCount());

    SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ftpCursor, fields, to);
    dataSource.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.upload_screen_spinner);
    s.setAdapter(dataSource);
```

The Log line returns a getCount() of 4 on the cursor, so I know the cursor has data in it.  When the spinner opens, there is no data in it at all.  I figure it must be something stupid but I just can't see it.

Comment: Is it possible that you have 4 records of empty strings, you wouldn't see much of anything if that happened...

Comment: No, those records are retrieved elsewhere in the app and they aren't empty.

Comment: Then there is probably data in it but your layout for the items is not showing anything...

Comment: I know the cursor has data in it.  The Log.i line reports that there are 4 records in the cursor.  I'm trying to figure out why the layout isn't showing anything.

Comment: The easiest way is to reduce your layout down to a single TextView

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working.  I think the catalyzing fix was changing the layout in the SimpleCursorAdapter to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

```
final String from[] = {  "siteName","_id" };
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor ftpCursor = database.query("ftptable", from, null, null, null, null, null);

SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ftpCursor, from, to);

ftpCursor.moveToFirst();
database.close();


Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.upload_screen_spinner);
s.setAdapter(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ***from*** array has two values while your ***to*** array has one field. Try removing the "_id" and see if it works.

Comment: the _id field is required for the cursoradapter.  I already know that's not the issue, anyway.  I've got a similar field/to cursoradapter in another part of the application that does the same thing. the single to field just defaults to the first column in the from array.